Getting Crash in InApp Update when migrating from Play Core Library
We're migrating from com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 to new approach as mentioned in this migration guide - https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#groovy . However, after following the steps as mentioned in the doc, app is getting crashed when launching it.
Crash Logs are as below -
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getAppUpdateInfo()Lcom/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task; 
in class Lcom/google/android/play/core/appupdate/AppUpdateManager; or its super classes 
(declaration of 'com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateManager' appears in 
/data/app/~~aDy2HTRM_e1Hy6YWUAl7FA==/com.et.epaper-uBsx8lP3gN-by8Jo1VJufg==/base.apk!classes19.dex)
    at com.x.x.xx.XActivity.checkForAppUpdate(XActivity.kt:400)
    at com.x.x.xx.XActivity.onCreate(XActivity.kt:257)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)

Below are the new dependencies we're using in our App's Build.gradle file -
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0'

In the migration guide, it is mentioned that there's change in dependencies only and no code level changes. We have also compared our existing code for InApp update with the new code and it is same.
Any help is appreciated.

Did you perform the Common Migration Steps
After that it should work

Thanks for your answer. I have already followed the Common Migration Steps. Looks like It was an issue with my Studio and cache. Tried Invalidate cache and Refresh Gradle Dependencies solved the issue.
